# When creating queries, I get an error, prompted that you should specify the table from which the user code will be taken

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

I don't know how to do this technically, if it's not difficult, I wanted to know how to add another column to the gap. That is, to the column `plus_k_health`, add another columns `plus_k_bron` and `plus_k_sile`.

Unfortunately, I do not even know approximately how to do this.

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a query of this form:

```
SELECT * INTO some_name
FROM (SELECT p.*, i.*, ...) AS some_name;
```

I have added a space between `*` and `INTO`, you should do that too.

Besides, I strongly recommend you to use a different name for the variable you are selecting into from the relation you are naming for the result of your subselect.

Finally, the actual error tells you that in your inner select you specify the same column.

So, since I do not have Cyrillic alphabet at hand and you did not provide me the means to easily copy-paste the names you are using, I will pretend that the duplicate column had the name of `some_other_name`.

So, this column by this name exists both in `p` and `i` and you and up with a temporary table resulting from a subselect with duplicate column names. The solution is to actually list the columns from `p` and `i` you want to select and rename duplicates, like

```
SELECT ..., p.some_other_name AS p_other_name, i.some_other_name AS i_other_name
FROM ...
```

BTW, it's dangerous to use `SELECT *` in your `SELECT` clause instead of actually listing the columns you want to select, because of:

- the possibility of accidentally leaking sensitive information, like accidentally selecting IBAN values and showing the result of the query at inappropriate places
- the possibility of selecting many columns you do not need, possibly bunary large objects as well in tens of millions which:

  - harms performance
  - creates server load spikes and possibly crashes and undesired behavior
  - burdens your server network
  - slows down client device when he is waiting for all the unnecessary data to be found, copied into memory, copied into network, downloaded and then parsed
- column duplication in subselects
- superfluous, difficult-to-read results